# Add TextBox to DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, textbox

I have a web page built in .NET where I am a very simple DataGrid with several fields.  I would like to have one of those field have its data placed in a TextBox so the user can edit the default description.  Is there an easy way to do this by default so the user doesn't have to click an edit button for the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, disable `AutoGenerateColumns` and define your own fields:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Data") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Updating this data to the database might be more difficult though.

Comment: You should read the question carefully, OP clearly mentioned **DateGrid** not GridView :-)

Comment: Oops. I have never seen a `DataGrid` Apparently it is a .NET 1.0 control made obsolete in 2004. +1 for noticing my mistake :)